# Emacs - installation in Vista

Tags: emacs

I haven't used emacs but have heard about its features and really want to try it out. So can someone post the procedure how to install it in win vista. And the links to download its setup and stuffs so that i can get it setup on my lap?

Comment: I wonder why no one has down rated this question yet. :|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is probably using [EmacsW32](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/EmacsW32.html) which is nicely integrated into Windows and comes with a proper Windows installer.

Answer (score 3):

Quick answer: [The GNU Emacs FAQ for Windows](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/windows/ntemacs.html)

Comment: yep, I just use the precompiled .zip on Vista, as described in this doc. http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/windows/Getting-Emacs.html#Getting-Emacs   Unpack the zip file, and it's ready to go.